# How to share service data between components correctly in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, components, observers

I want to create a service to get data from .json file once and share it to multiple subscribers. But now with my solution number of requests to get data from .json file equals to a number of a subscibers for my service.

getconfig.service.ts

```js
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from "angular2/http";

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    config: any;
    http: Http;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
        console.log('Inside service');
        this.config = this.http.get('/config.json');
    }

}
```

robotui.component.ts

```js
...
import {ConnectionService} from '../services/connection.service';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ConfigService, ConnectionService]
  ...
})

constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {
  this._configService.config.subscribe((observer) => {
    console.log('Subscribe in RobotUI component', JSON.parse(observer._body));
  });
}
```

actual.photo.component.ts

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ConfigService} from '../services/getconfig.service';

@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ConfigService]
})

export class ActualPhotoComponent {

  constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {
    this._configService.config.subscribe((observer) => {
      console.log('Subscribe in ActualPhoto component', JSON.parse(observer._body));
    });
  }

}
```

When i run it in my console i see:

[image]

So, there is get request for each subscibers. I want a solution when i get config.json file only once, save this info in a service and share it with multiple subscibers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ConfigService]  //<--- this creates service instance per component
})
```

---

To share data among controllers/components and to create single instance only, you have to inject your service into `bootstrap function`.

```
import {ConfigService } from './path to service';

bootstrap('AppCompoent',[configService])  //<----Inject here it will create a single instance only
```

In subscribing component,

**robotui.component.ts**

```
...
import {ConfigService} from '../services/getconfig.service';  //<----- Note this line here....
import {ConnectionService} from '../services/connection.service';

@Component({
  ...
  ...  // No providers needed anymore
  ...
})

constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {
  this._configService.config.subscribe((observer) => {
    console.log('Subscribe in RobotUI component', JSON.parse(observer._body));
  });
}
```

**actual.photo.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {ConfigService} from '../services/getconfig.service';

@Component({
  ...
  ...  // No providers needed anymore...
})

export class ActualPhotoComponent {

  constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {
    this._configService.config.subscribe((observer) => {
      console.log('Subscribe in ActualPhoto component', JSON.parse(observer._body));
    });
  }

}
```

This is what you should do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified code with your recommendations. Now there is an error (No provider for Http): [http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/9_6_2016/17/SoKS0pVJkiij3iOBDz3AA.jpg](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/9_6_2016/17/SoKS0pVJkiij3iOBDz3AA.jpg).

Comment: You make sure that in bootstrap function you have injected HTTP_PROVIDERS--- `('AppComponent',[HTTP_PROVIDERS,configService])`;

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/HTTP_PROVIDERS-let.html import it and inject it into bootstrap function.

Comment: Yes. It helps and it works. One more question. How can i process a response to get necessary data not in subscribe() function JSON.parse(observer._body), but inside service ?

Comment: In service within `.map() function` you can play with response and send only required data with `return keyword`.