# Pass data from one Component to another Component in angular4

Tags: angular, angular5

I have two Components(Component1 and Component2) in my Angular Application. These two components I have rendered in my app component.
Now I want to send a value from Component1 to Component2. How to Send it. Are there any best practices??

In Component1 I have a code Like this.
Component1.html

```
<button (click)="passData()">Click Me</button>
```

Component1.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit , Output , EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

   Component1Variable:string="Component1VariableSent";
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
   @Output()
   SendValue=new EventEmitter<string>();
   passData()
   {
        this.SendValue.emit(this.Component1Variable);
   }
}
```

In Component2.html I have

```
<app-component1 (SendValue)="ValueFromComp1($event)"> </app-component1>
{{ValueFromComponent1}}
```

In Component2.ts I have

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {
  ValueFromComponent1:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ValueFromComp1(var1:any)
  {
      this.ValueFromComponent1=var1;
  }

}
```

In appcomponent.html I hav code Like this.

```
<app-component1></app-component1>
<app-component2></app-component2>
```

Now I am getting to send the value from component1 to component2. But there is a click button two times in the output.

And another question is that I want to transfer data from one Component to another Component which resides in the same hirearchy of component tree.
By doing in the above way I am not getting the components in the same hirearchy of component tree.

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: did you do a search on google?

Comment: Yes I did a search.

Comment: best place to start https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @roopteja you are using event emitters just take a look at it and it will be good to go

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 4: How to pass API data from one component into another component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376442/angular-4-how-to-pass-api-data-from-one-component-into-another-component)

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways you can accomplish the same .

- [**Event Emitters**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/event) (For cases where components have parent child relation ship)
- [**Shared Services**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)
- [**Ngrx**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx) (a more expansive shared service for large projects)

Comment: there are plenty of questions similar, why you are answering the same

Comment: might be he is a starter to SO and he needs some help to begin with he can take it up from there @Sajeetharan i have seen you answer questions like this too

Comment: haha i did but not these days .it make sense if he provides code!

Comment: i get it but if he were specific i could have commented, but he wasnt had to answer . you DV if you want to i will take it down

Comment: Sajeetharan I have attached a code and my question also.Please take a look into it and answer. Thanks In advance

Comment: @roopteja sajeetharan is helping he is not here to answer your questions .  Its his obligation

Comment: Sorry My english is not good. My apologies to Sajeetharan. Would you please look into the code and help me accordingly.

Comment: Rahul I have studied somewhere that Component Interactions(Child Component to Child Component ) in Angular is done by Sending the value from child to parent and then to the corresponding child. Is that true and does it work for all scenarios of component Interaction.

Comment: @roopteja For complex interactions i will always suggest you to use shared services much easier to debug and also write code , ya the thing you mentioned can be done but it is combersome

Comment: Rahul If I execute the above program I am getting 2 buttons in my main html page. How to get rid of that

Comment: @Rahul In the above comment you just mentioned complex interactions but I am simply passing a string variable from one component to another component.

Answer (score 4):

If you are passing data from parent component to your child component you should use **`@input`**.

In your case you want to pass data from one component to another which are in the same level. i would suggest you to go for shared service.

Look at this **[`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376442/angular-4-how-to-pass-api-data-from-one-component-into-another-component/47385677#47385677)** to get more details.