# Angular 6 how to pass selected Object from BehaviourSubject<Object[]> to component using service?

Tags: angular, service, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have a component like this using an apiService, where I follow this approach using BehaviourSubject to share data from my API: 
[Angular 4: How to pass API data from one component into another component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376442/angular-4-how-to-pass-api-data-from-one-component-into-another-component/47385677#47385677)

settings.component.ts :

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: Observable<Setting[]>;
  public selectedSetting: Setting;

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
            private router: Router) { }

  // Load Setting while starting
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.getSettings();
    this.data = this.apiService.fetchData();
  }

  onSelect(setting: Setting): void {
    this.selectedSetting = setting;
  }

  clearSelect(): void {
    this.selectedSetting = null;
  }

  goToSettingDetail(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['settingsDetail']);
  }
}
```

api.service.ts:

```
export class ApiService {

  private API_URL = 'someUrl';
  public subject$: BehaviorSubject<Setting[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Setting[]>([]);


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  // use async pipe in html template "*ngFor= let s of settings | async"
  // and just inject ApiService in components constructor
  fetchData() {
    const fetch$: Observable <Setting[]> = this.getSettings().pipe(share());
    fetch$.pipe(
        map(allSettings => this.subject$.next(allSettings))
      )
      .subscribe();
    return fetch$;
  }

  /** GET settings from API*/
  getSettings(): Observable<Setting[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Setting[]>(this.API_URL + '/settings')
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getSettings', []))
      );
  }
}
```

So if I have a part in a html file like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <th align="left">Id</th>
  </tr>

  <tr *ngFor="let s of data | async">
    <td>{{s.Id}}</td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="onSelect(s); goToSettingsDetail()">ViewSettings</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the correct way with still using BehaviourSubject for getting selected Object in other components? If I use an additional service, which fetchs the selected object from settingsComponent it isn't related with BehaviourSubject anymore right? So if I do changes on selected object in other component, no one will notice.

Can you give me some hints? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would push your selected setting into your service. Then you can subscribe to selections within your sub-component.

```js
export class ApiService {
  private _selectedSetting$: BehaviorSubject<Setting> = new BehaviorSubject<Setting>(null);
  public selectedSetting$: Observable<Setting> = this._selectedSetting$.asObservable();

  ...

  public setSelectedSetting(s: Setting) {
    this._selectedSetting$.next(s);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I call for example in main.component.ts:<br>
setSelectedSetting(s: Setting) { this.apiService.setSelectedSetting(s)}
<br>
Now in subcomponent.ts:<br>
1. Inject apiService<br>
2. selectedSetting: Observable<Setting> = this.apiService.selectedSetting$.subscribe()<br>

Comment: Yes. You could even have `<foo bar="apiService.selectedSetting$ | async">` in your template if that makes sense for your component.`