# Sharing Data from one component to another using BehaviorSubject returns null

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I am trying to share data from one component to another using BehaviorSubject but when i subscribe to observable in the **Target Component** it returns **null**

This is my **Service Class**

```
 private apiData = new BehaviorSubject<Patient>(null);
 public apiData$ = this.apiData.asObservable();

getSinglePatient(id) {

this.loadToken();
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.authToken);
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/patient/' + id, { headers: 
headers });
}

setData(data) {

  this.apiData.next(data);

}
```

This is my **Primary Class** where i get data

```
 getSinglePatient(id: any) {

  this.patientService.getSinglePatient(id).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.patients = data; //<-- Patients is an Array 
  this.patientService.setData(data);
  this.router.navigate(['/records']);
  console.log(data);

});
```

This is my **Target Class** where I want to Display/Retrive Data

```
patient: Patient;
constructor(private patientService: PatientService) {

this.patientService.apiData$.subscribe(patient => console.log(patient));
}
```

This is my **Console Output**

[image: Log]

I Referred to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376442/angular-4-how-to-pass-api-data-from-one-component-into-another-component/47385677#47385677)

Not sure whats wrong as this the first time I'm doing this. Thanks.

Comment: where did you declared provider for `patientService` ?

Comment: @SunilSingh I'm declaring it in the **app.module** and in both **Priamry Class** and **Target Class**

Comment: Do not provide in Primary Class and Target Class.

Comment: @SunilSingh Oh wow it actually worked. Can you Please Explain why did U mentioned it? and can u please write it as an answer so that i can mark it

Comment: Each providers creates the new instance of class. If you want to communicate through service class then its not necessary to have same reference of Object. If provide in multiple places, all will have their own version of class.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much for explaining. This what it’s meant when people say it should be a singleton?

Comment: yes, now you got it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set **`apiData$`** once you assign ,

```
setData(data) {
  this.apiData.next(data);
  this.apiData$ = this.apiData.asObservable();
}
```

**EDIT:**

You do not necessarily have to do the above, Just have the service configured in the app.module level.Not in each of the class since they will create an instance each time, the values will be vanished.

Comment: I did this change and now I'm getting an error saying 'Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'