# How to pass the data from one component to another

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I need to pass an id of object from one component to another.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">
         <button mat-icon-button (click)="Edit()"><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>             
      </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Edit() function opens a form(another component) in which I would like to use something like user.id value. How can I pass the data between components? Is it possible to initialize a value and export it to another component in html code? Or is there any another solution? I would like to add that all the data is provided by service, MongoDB database.

Comment: U want to open window like MatDialog ? Or use component in array list ?

Comment: MatDialog in which i need to "inject" data by id property (edit form)

Comment: just try EventEmitter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing data from parent component to your child component you should use `@input`.

In your case you want to pass data from one component to another which are in the same level. i would suggest you to go for **`shared service`**.

Look at this **[`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376442/angular-4-how-to-pass-api-data-from-one-component-into-another-component/47385677#47385677)** to get more details.